# Dynamic CSS through PHP issue

Tags: php, css

I am trying to create a dynamic style.php stylesheet. The most basic function I am testing is a color picker on my theme-options. The color picker works, but my dynamic css file does not. On Chrome I am receiving a 'Illegal string offset' error when I inspect the nav element. I can confirm that it is recognizing and echoing the string, but not the value.

My dynamic css file:

```
<?php
  $absolute_path = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
  $wp_load = $absolute_path[0] . 'wp-load.php';
  require_once($wp_load);

  $novus_nav_color = get_option('novus_nav_color');

  header('Content-type: text/css');
  header('Cache-control: must-revalidate');
?>

.contain-to-grid .top-bar {
  background-color: <?php echo $novus_nav_color{'novus_nav_color'} ?>;
}
```

I am using Foundation 5 stock css. Site can be found [here](http://www.elevancement.com/novus-theme/)

Can anyone direct me on what I am doing wrong? Full error string is below:

```
.contain-to-grid .top-bar {
background-color: <br /> <b>Warning</b>: Illegal string offset 'novus_nav_color' in     <b>/home/flannelbeard/public_html/novus-theme/wp-content/themes/project.novus.theme/css/dynamic.style.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br /> #;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow I am an idiot. Ok, here is my error.

```
.contain-to-grid .top-bar {
  background-color: <?php echo $novus_nav_color; ?>;
}
```

I needed to just echo the variable and it was trying to call a string.